# How to increase NER accuracy of Stanford's CRF for a small training dataset?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to train a NER model for a different domain using the Stanford's Named Entity Recognizer module (https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html) and the tag set is quite varied. The size of my dataset is : around 1100 sentences for training and 150 sentences for testing. The problem that I am facing is my test accuracy is coming out to be very low : 20-40%.

I tried to play with the different features provided in the NERFeatureFactory but none of them are actually helping. What could be the actual problem with this? Is it only because of the limited amount of training data or am I missing something else as well?

The other thing that I want to try is to do some fine-tuning and validation on the trained model. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: How many tags do you have ?

Comment: I have 22 tags following BIO tagging mechanism.